# Notational questions about rules in type theory

Tags: logic, notation, type-theory

[Definition of contexts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16GnD.png) from [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01913662/file/luo_19101.pdf). The first rule says that the empty tuple (or sequence) is a context. The second and third ones I don't exactly understand.

I think the second has the premise "if A is a type in context $\Gamma$ and $x$ is not a free variable in $\Gamma$", but what is the meaning of whatever is under the horizontal line? More specifically, what does "valid" refer to -- does it refer to $x: A$, or does it refer to $\Gamma, x: A$ ? If the latter, then is $\Gamma, x: A$  regarded as a tuple/sequence and hence a context that is "produced" from $\Gamma$ by adding $x:A$, and the authors just chose omit the $()$ or $\langle \rangle$?

I'm also not sure if I understand these [inference rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idVnS.png). In the sequence $\Gamma, x:A, \Gamma' \ valid$, does "valid" refer to the tuple/sequence $\Gamma, x:A, \Gamma'$? Can this premise be phrased in words as "if we have a context (i.e., a tuple/sequence) in which $x: A$ appears somewhere"?

Also, what's the meaning of the period in [the second rule here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW3aY.png) ($\lambda x: A.b:A\to B$)? The expression $\Gamma \vdash \lambda x: A$ intuitively means that $\lambda x $ is an object of type $A$ in context $\Gamma$, but what does $\Gamma \vdash \lambda x: A.b:A\to B$ intuitively mean?

Comment: On the last question: perhaps you should look up the notions of lambda abstraction and variable binding.

Comment: Judgements are sentence correctly written according to the syntactical rules and they are valid either by stipulation (sort of axioms) or because are derived using inference rules from previous valid jugments. Compare with valid formulas of usual logical calculus.

Comment: The rule says that if we can assert tha $A$ is a type and x is a fresh variable, i e a variable not occurring in the context $\Gamma$ we can use it to name an object whatever of type $A$.

Comment: The first inference rule simply amounts to saying that an assumption is consequence of itself.

Comment: Compare with $A \vdash A$ of ND and Sequent Caculus.